# Nested maps in Alloy

Tags: alloy

I'm trying to model nested maps in Alloy (e.g. `{a: {b: 3}}`) where mapping such as `{a: {a: 3}}` with the same key repeated are invalid. I tried to do this with the final fact listed below, but I'm obviously not modeling something correctly since Alloy reports no instances are found.

```
open util/natural

sig Key {}

sig NestedMap { map: Key -> Key -> one Natural }

// Force a non-empty map to exist
fact { #NestedMap > 0 }
fact { all m: NestedMap | #m.map > 0 }

// Adding this fact makes Alloy unable to find any instances
fact { all d: NestedMap |
        all k1: Key |
        all k2: Key |
        all count: Natural |
        ((k1 -> k2 -> count) in d.map) => k1 != k2
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A -> B -> one C` means that every single `A -> B` must be mapped to *exactly one* C. This includes `key1 -> key1`, which is incompatible with your `fact`. You probably instead wanted to say that every single `A -> B` must be mapped to *at most one* C, which can be done with `A -> B -> lone C`.